# View is null when using kotlinx synthetic on orientation changed

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

**Myview is null in viewmodel's observer if and only if after orientation change**

I used kotlinx synthetic all views are initiated but those view throw null object exception that accessed in viewmodel's observer

this is my import

```
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_story.user_avatar
```

Everything is good but when orientation is changed then it throws null pointer exception but other views are initiated expect in viewmodel's observer scope

```
   personInfoViewModel.shortUserInfo.observe(this , Observer {shortInfo ->

       userAvatar.setOnClickListener {

        })
```

I couldn't find where the things going wrong then i tried

```
    userAvatar = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.user_avatar)
```

and access this works for me every time even after orientation changed

```
    personInfoViewModel.shortUserInfo.observe(this , Observer {shortInfo ->

       userAvatar.setOnClickListener {

        })
```

**I strange what's wrong with**

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_story.user_avatar
```

**after orientation changed**

Comment: did you try something like var localUserAvatar = userAvatar; then use localUserAvatar in "observe"? Looks like closure is copied and this copy is used instead of property "userAvatar"

Answer (score 0):

View cache is not cleared after calling `onDestroyView()` when you import only particular views. You need to import the whole package to make it work.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
```